# Installation of ionic sidemenu results in "zliberror: zlib: unexpected end of file"

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

My npm version: 6.4.1
node: 10.14.1
Ionic: 4.7.0
Cordova: 8.1.2 (Basically all of them are of the latest version)

When I try to install an ionic sidemenu at a specific location, an error occurs as such:

```
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on 
reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\15432\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01- 
12T00_54_51_838Z-debug.log
```

So I navigate to the log document and have a look on the end of the file:

```
1474 silly saveTree | +-- path-to-regexp@1.7.0
1474 silly saveTree | | `-- isarray@0.0.1
1474 silly saveTree | `-- serviceworker-cache-polyfill@4.0.0
1474 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.8.26
1475 verbose stack ZlibError: zlib: unexpected end of file
1475 verbose stack     at Zlib.(anonymous function).onerror (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:131:21)
1475 verbose stack     at Unzip.write (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:255:31)
1475 verbose stack     at Unzip.flush (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:222:10)
1475 verbose stack     at Unzip.end (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:229:10)
1475 verbose stack     at Object.end (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:415:21)
1475 verbose stack     at PassThrough.onend (_stream_readable.js:628:10)
1475 verbose stack     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
1475 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:187:15)
1475 verbose stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
1475 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback 
(internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
1476 verbose cwd D:\Coursera Doc\Ionic\conFusion
1477 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
1478 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
1479 verbose node v10.14.1
1480 verbose npm  v6.4.1
1481 error code Z_BUF_ERROR
1482 error errno -5
1483 error zlib: unexpected end of file
1484 verbose exit [ -5, true ]
```

I really have no idea what this means. So I try to type "npm install" and fix all the problems on the subfolder in which I create my sidemenu, and the same issue, as above, occurs. 
I hope that anyone can help me address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to be a `DNS` issue when connecting to `npm` registry.

Please check (https://status.npmjs.org/) first to see if all services are operational then clear your `npm` cache.

Force `clean` your `npm cache` by doing:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: I was having the same problem as the person that asked the question and the "npm cache clean --force" worked for me. How does this not answer the question?

Comment: If you think it is a solution, just update/format your answer and add more explanation to it, so it would be helpful for future users. :)

Comment: Am still all new to this, thanks for the support. better now?

Comment: Now, it's better surely.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with the node version 10.15.0 installed on my machine. I got a very similar error while installing the `ts-node-dev`.

```
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-30T07_38_27_700Z-debug.log
```

I tried the `npm cache clean --force` command but that didn't solve the problem.

Finally, I upgraded my node to version `16.13.0` and that solved the issue.