# How to install the local version of Javascript Obfuscator.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, clone, obfuscation

There is https://obfuscator.io which is the Web UI of the Javascript Obfuscator by Timofey Kachalov

The project is available on Github : https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator-ui

I've tried "git clone" but I can't get it to work from local. Also I've tried all commands in the README.md but nothing.

Please, someone could give me detail of all the commands to get it work for me ? Is it possible to get local server name like http://obfuscator.local ? (instead of http://localhost:3000/)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried after command as README.md showed

```
git clone https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator-ui.git

npm install
npm run updatesemantic
npm run webpack:dev

node server.js
```

But I got this answer:

```
> javascript-obfuscator-web@3.14.8 start /home/user/javascript-obfuscator-ui
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:438
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './dist' is not defined by "exports" in /home/user/javascript-obfuscator-ui/node_modules/threads/package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:513:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kim/javascript-obfuscator-ui/server.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

The application runs after editing exports option of package.json like below at ./node_modules/threads/package.json.

from:

```
 "exports": {
    "./": {
      "require": "./dist/index.js",
      "default": "./index.mjs"
    },
    "./observable": {
      "require": "./observable.js",
      "default": "./observable.mjs"
    },
    "./register": {
      "require": "./register.js",
      "default": "./register.mjs"
    },
    "./worker": {
      "require": "./worker.js",
      "default": "./worker.mjs"
    }
  },
```

to:

```
  "exports": {
    "./dist": {
      "require": "./dist/index.js",
      "default": "./index.mjs"
    },
    "./observable": {
      "require": "./observable.js",
      "default": "./observable.mjs"
    },
    "./register": {
      "require": "./register.js",
      "default": "./register.mjs"
    },
    "./worker": {
      "require": "./worker.js",
      "default": "./worker.mjs"
    }
  },
```

And I tried `node server.js` and the application runs on `localhost:3000/`.
Maybe there is right solution. You can ask the question on [this app's gitpage](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator-ui/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc) too(asking the author is better).

Comment: "npm install" gives me a lot of warnings and finally an error like this : https://tinypix.top/images/2021/01/20/ZobEi.jpg

Comment: @RapieraAgnay Then I couldn't help the problem. Maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155947/installation-of-ionic-sidemenu-results-in-zliberror-zlib-unexpected-end-of-fi).

Comment: "npm cache clean --force" is helpful

Comment: @RapieraAgnay Happy your problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Open PowerShell window
execute npm install -g javascript-obfuscator

Step 2 : javascript-obfuscator.cmd  @@SOURCE_FILE_PATH  --output   @@DESTINATION_FILE_PATH

```
     (I am using Excel to generate above statement for bulk obfuscatation by giving source and destination path)
```

Step 3 : Hurray. obfuscated File created. Enjoy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).